# How to uninstall Realplayer 11 (Gold)?

Tags: uninstall

I accidentally installed sometime ago the Realplayer to test embedding videos inside PDFs. Anyhow this turned out not to work and wouldn't have been portable eitherway, so I decide to get rid of this tool again. Since its not a package I cannot uninstall with apt-get or dpkg. Its Realplayer 11 Gold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know the files it installed. So basically what I would suggest is to find out their locations with:

```
sudo updatedb
locate realplayer
```

Then you can delete all those files, and it is hopefully gone.

Comment: Yes, I got the location /usr/local/Realplayer but inside there is a install.log saying there has been something installed also into /usr/share, meaning beside that location (should be /usr/local/share). So I think I must go through this install.log inorder to manually remove all the installed files, hopeing that I don't miss any. (Crappy software! BTW)

Comment: Yeah, the install log should give you all you need!

Comment: Yes but there were a lots of commands I never was aware of, xdg-icon-ressource, chcon,... It turned out that everything is fine again. Thanks.

Comment: I guess those just update the caches of different things, they should be updated at some point by apt-get I assume.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you have to run the postuninstall script first.
When installed in the /opt folder it is:

`sudo /opt/real/RealPlayer/postinst/postuninst.sh`

Then it is safe to remove the /opt/real folder and subfolders.

When installed in another folder, run the postuninst.sh script from that folder

Comment: Nope there is no such postuninstall.sh file here.

Comment: Ok, I had used it some time ago. Glad you fixed it.